# why does `brew uninstall --cask miniconda` require my password?

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

I'm using Homebrew on macOS with M1 pro, in a non-admin standard user account. (I also have access to an admin account, but I deliberately created a standard account to mess around with Brew).

I installed brew by simply untarring the git repo into my homedir. I also installed miniconda without a problem with `brew install --cask miniconda`. At no point was I asked for my password.

However, now I'm trying to `brew uninstall --cask miniconda`, and it asked for my password. What the heck? Why?

And to make things worse, after I typed in my password, it said I'm "is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported."

Full output:

```
david-dev@Davids-MBP ~ % brew uninstall --cask miniconda
==> Uninstalling Cask miniconda
==> Removing files:
/Users/david-dev/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base
Password:
david-dev is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

What makes this more confusing is that `/Users/david-dev/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base` was created by me using `brew install`, and thus owned by me, so why is it asking for my password? I thought the whole philosophy of brew is to not ask for the password except for in the very beginning if I decide to go with the default prefix (in this case I did not). Is it simply because I didn't go with the default password that it exhibited this strange behavior?

Comment: this is offtopic here as it is not about programming. You can try https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation): *do yourself a favour and use the installer to install to the default prefix. Some things may not build when installed elsewhere. One of the reasons Homebrew just works relative to the competition is because we recommend installing here. Pick another prefix at your peril!* (by prefix, they mean the initial path - `/usr/local`.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be an instance of something not building, in fact Conda worked totally fine when I had it.